# How to stop automatic high dpi webpage scaling in ie11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, meta-tags, internet-explorer-11

With today's win8.1 update, we got new IE11 which automatically scales websites on high dpi monitors (actually it even scales 1920x1080 to 125% on 15'' screen)

When testing couple of parallax websites I made some time ago (used scrollorama), I noticed that this scaling effect bugs out my predefined scroll points on which certain animations occur.

**Is there a way to stop this behavior?**

I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265030(v=vs.85).aspx

but, explicitly setting `X-UA-TextLayoutMetrics` to either `gdi` or `normal` doesn't seem to do the work for me, are there any prerequisites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer i found was to actually play along with browsers default behavior and to adapt incompatible websites.

Answer (score 0):

For my HTML pages I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In addition to that you can add:

```
maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0
```

inside `content="      "`